# why do I need to initialize variable in begin block

Tags: awk

I have run the following code :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ color["one"]="red"; color["two"]="orange";print color["one"] }'
```

and got

```
red
```

However, when I execute the following two codes :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ color["one"]="red"; color["two"]="orange"}{print color["one"] }'
```

and

```
awk '{ color["one"]="red"; color["two"]="orange";print color["one"] }'
```

the execution does not seem to work. Why can't I put `color["one"]` in the body block for the first not working code? Also, why do I have to put `color["one"]="red"; color["two"]="orange";print color["one"]` in the begin block? Thank you.

Comment: For your question of using `color` array values in `BEGIN` section it is up to your requirement where do you want to use it, since you have NOT told us sample input and expected sample output so difficult to tell, though initiating an array in `BEGIN` section should be good so you need NOT to initiate or create it again and again in main section of `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is expected behavior since `BEGIN` section in `awk` executed before reading an Input_file so it *does not* require you to pass any Input_file name hence your 1st `awk` works. But in your other `awk` you *closed* the `BEGIN` section and then opened a *main block* by `{...}` so it requires a Input_file to execute it.

See following from `man awk` page too:

> BEGIN and END are two special kinds of patterns which are not tested against the input.  The action parts of all BEGIN patterns are
>   merged as if
>          all the statements had been written in a single BEGIN block.  They are executed before any of the input is read.  Similarly, all the
>   END  blocks
>          are  merged,  and  executed  when all the input is exhausted (or when an exit statement is executed).  BEGIN and END patterns
>   cannot be combined
>          with other patterns in pattern expressions.  BEGIN and END patterns cannot have missing action parts.

***Your 1st*** `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ color["one"]="red"; color["two"]="orange";print color["one"] }'
```

After `BEGIN` section *no* statements are given so it works expected and gives `red` as output.

---

---

Your 2nd `awk`: Let us divide it in 2 parts

***1st part (for understanding):***

```
awk 'BEGIN{ color["one"]="red"; color["two"]="orange"}
```

***2nd part (for understanding):***

```
{print color["one"] }'
```

So 1st part is `BEGIN` section and 2nd part is *main block* which expects an Input_file is to be passed to `awk` program.

***Answer for why initializing variables or arrays in*** `BEGIN` ***section:*** 
For your question why one has to initiate variables or array in `BEGIN` block is since `BEGIN` section gets executed before main block when Input_file is being read, so it is good to have all initialization of variables and arrays there to avoid them re-initiating or initiating them with a condition (which will be checked each time each line is being read). That is why it is recommended IMHO to initialize them in `BEGIN` section.

Comment: Oh I see! You need an input file for the body block! Thank you very much for your clear explanation!